# UTF-8 decoding in Spring Boot GET request to static resource

Tags: spring, encoding, utf-8, get, character-encoding

I have this `@Bean` redirecting requests to my Spring Boot backend.

```
@Bean
WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/data/static/images/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/static/img/");
        }
    };
}
```

It works perfectly for URLs such as:

`http://localhost:4200/data/static/images/champion/tiles/Ahri_0.jpg`

But not for URLs such as:

`http://localhost:4200/data/static/images/champion/tiles/Tahm%20Kench_0.jpg`

The image is correctly shown in my Angular2 front end if the `champion` name does not contain any of: space, ampersand or single quote characters.

I ran a trace level logging debug and made both types of requests -- one with and without a "bad" character.  Currently, it seems as if the backend searches for the correct file.  However, it turns out that it claims it can't find it.  I quintuple checked the file in my insanity, I know it is there and that the path printed is correct.

Here is an example log message:

```
2018-11-18 05:07:14.496 TRACE 9897 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@4d0bdef0] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-11-18 05:07:14.497 DEBUG 9897 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/data/static/images/champion/tiles/Tahm Kench_0.jpg] are [/data/static/images/**, /**]
2018-11-18 05:07:14.497 DEBUG 9897 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/data/static/images/champion/tiles/Tahm Kench_0.jpg] are {}
2018-11-18 05:07:14.497 DEBUG 9897 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/data/static/images/champion/tiles/Tahm Kench_0.jpg] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[URL [file:/home/nuradin/Development/Java/riot-api-interface/static/img/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@5b5b59]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-11-18 05:07:14.497 TRACE 9897 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@132f4851]
2018-11-18 05:07:14.497 TRACE 9897 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@5b8d72dc]
2018-11-18 05:07:14.498 DEBUG 9897 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/data/static/images/champion/tiles/Tahm%20Kench_0.jpg] is: -1
2018-11-18 05:07:14.498 DEBUG 9897 --- [on(7)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(7)-127.0.0.1: (port 34127) op = 82
2018-11-18 05:07:14.498 TRACE 9897 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Resolving resource for request path "champion/tiles/Tahm Kench_0.jpg"
2018-11-18 05:07:14.498 TRACE 9897 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: URL [file:/home/nuradin/Development/Java/riot-api-interface/static/img/]
```

---

EDIT: I've implemented the class in the accepted answer, and it's definitely working because I printed the resource name (after encoding the characters I had trouble with.)  However, the result is still a 404 error.

Log is below.  The `champion/Aatrox2Epng` bit is due to a `println` statement in the method @slimane posted below.

```
2018-11-18 05:56:40.509 TRACE 12951 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@465ac973]
2018-11-18 05:56:40.509 TRACE 12951 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@37df7ae5]
2018-11-18 05:56:40.509 DEBUG 12951 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/data/static/images/champion/Aatrox.png] is: -1
2018-11-18 05:56:40.509 TRACE 12951 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.CachingResourceResolver        : Resolving resource for request path "champion/Aatrox.png"
2018-11-18 05:56:40.510 TRACE 12951 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.r.c.EncodedPathResourceResolver      : Resolving resource for request path "champion/Aatrox.png"
2018-11-18 05:56:40.510 TRACE 12951 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.r.c.EncodedPathResourceResolver      : Checking location: URL [file:/home/nuradin/Development/Java/riot-api-interface/static/8.23.1/img]
champion/Aatrox2Epng
2018-11-18 05:56:40.511 TRACE 12951 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.r.c.EncodedPathResourceResolver      : No match for location: URL [file:/home/nuradin/Development/Java/riot-api-interface/static/8.23.1/img]
2018-11-18 05:56:40.511 TRACE 12951 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : No matching resource found - returning 404
2018-11-18 05:56:40.511 DEBUG 12951 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
```

another EDIT -- sorry for the confusion, I changed the path because I thought paths with periods would work now.

```
@Bean
WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/data/static/images/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/static/8.23.1/img")
                    .resourceChain(true)
                    .addResolver(encodedPathResourceResolver());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: recent logs shows [file:/home/nuradin/Development/Java/riot-api-interface/static/8.23.1/img] but old one [file:/home/nuradin/Development/Java/riot-api-interface/**static**/img/], are you still having the same config as shown above?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion, I changed it because I thought I'd be able to use periods in path names now.  I'll double check everything but I'm pretty sure the path is correct.  I've been trying permutations of all the settings for the last 6 hours

editing the OP with new `addResourceHandlers()`

Comment: can you try add a / in ..../img/ i mean in your resourceLocation

Comment: Nice one, about 90% of my pictures are now loading in Angular2 under path `8.23.1` (which wasn't working before due to `the . symbol`)  However, the ones with special characters are not yet loading.  I removed all implementation except for the `return` in the `PathResourceResolver` and simply printed the `resource` parameter.  The result is lots of entries such as:

`champion/Nunu%20%26%20Willump.png
champion/Rek%27Sai.png
champion/Twisted%20Fate.png`

Comment: if I understand, you skipped replacing whitespace in the configuration but you still see %20 in the filename, try to replace it with a whitespace instead and see what you can get

Comment: I'll try that.  Thanks for all the help :)  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: It worked, thanks! All pictures show up regardless of what characters the file names contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your own PathResourceResolver as below:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceResolver;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomPathResourceResolver extends PathResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {

    @Override
    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
        //fixes problems with whitespaces in url
        resourcePath = resourcePath.replace(" ","%20");
        return super.getResource(resourcePath, location);
    }
}
```

and then register it in your configuration:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/data/static/images/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/static/img/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new CustomPathResourceResolver())
                ;
    }
```

Comment: It seems to be doing the same thing.  The trace messages show that nothing has changed.  I added the method to the `ResourceHandler` and implemented `PathResourceResolver`

Any idea?

Comment: hmm, nothing has changed does it mean it didn't take into consideration your CustompathResourceResolver?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the Problem for me. Somehow the path was encoded 2 times.
This removes all URI encoding not just whitespaces.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/Q:/Technik/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new CustomPathResourceResolver());
}

public class CustomPathResourceResolver extends PathResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {

    @Override
    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
        //fixes problems with special chars in url
        log.debug(resourcePath);
        resourcePath = UriUtils.decode(resourcePath, "UTF-8");
        log.debug(resourcePath);
        resourcePath = UriUtils.decode(resourcePath, "UTF-8");
        log.debug(resourcePath);
        return super.getResource(resourcePath, location);
    }
}
```